# A command similar to "dir" in git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I want to see the files in my current directory in git. For example, in linux **dir** command shows the files in current directory. Is there such a command in git?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `git ls-files` to see all the files included in git. For the current directory only, use `ls`.